# use a small circle icon marker instead of default marker icon with polyline

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet plugin to show google map with marker and polyline.
When I use default marker I am getting marker attached properly with polyline.
but when I changed the default marker with small circle icon image then that is not properly attached .

I am attching the screenshot . Please let me know How can I solve this ?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, there are some heights/widths You need to give when changing markers, as the center of the marker is not at the coordinate it depicts.

This example from the documentation shows that You set them on the Icon

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'my-icon.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
    shadowSize: [68, 95],
    shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
});
L.marker([50.505, 30.57], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
```